# Passing struct into function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100000

typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} DATE;

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float hrlyWage;
    float hrsWorked;
    float regPay;
    float otPay;
    float totalPay;
    DATE payDate;
} PAYRECORD;

int newRecord(struct PAYRECORD record[], int index){
    //set name to \0 so it can work as string
    record[index].name = {'\0'};
    index++;
    return index;
}

int main(){
    char menuChoice = 'X';
    struct PAYRECORD record[SIZE];
    int index = 0;

    while (menuChoice != 'Q'){
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        menuChoice = runMenu();
        switch (menuChoice){
            case 'A':
                index = newRecord(record, index);
        }
    }
}
```

main sets up an array of structs the gets passed into newRecord, and the goal is to make it so that I can input the data here and then return the new index to keep track of my array of structs. However something is going wrong where my program doesn't seem to be recognizing newRecord as a function, which ends up throwing the whole program off.
I get syntax errors for all the functions inside of newRecord, though I beleive it's because, as I mentioned, the program seems to be unable to recognize newRecord as a User defined Function.

Comment: *However something is going wrong* this can mean anything, explain what goes wrong. Also shows us how you declare the variable and how you call `newRecord`.

Comment: Where is your main?

Comment: You've used `typedef`, yet you're using `struct PAYRECORD record[]` later. Change it to `PAYRECORD record[]`

Comment: please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I suspect you are compiling with a C++ compiler.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @chux All C programs compile correctly in C++ compilers

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh No, not all C programs compile correctly in C++ compilers.

Comment: @chux Can you enlighten me please with some reference/example?
[I know of these unconventional ones though](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-c-program-wont-compiler-c/)

Comment: You said it yourself with the link. It is a mistake to believe that C is a subset of C++.

Comment: Not everything in the C standard is in the C++ standard.  A simple example is C99's Variable Length Arrays are not supported in C++.

Comment: Yes, but then why would you suspect the same for the question here?

Comment: Simple example of a line which will not compile in C++ but will in C: `int new;`

Comment: ok - so SHOW US THE ERROR you are getting

Comment: can u guys arguing about c vs c++ go elsewhere, its just confusing noise

Comment: By All C programs I meant All conventional C programs. The code in the question here doesn't seem to be using anything unconventional...

Comment: You are being optimistic expecting `struct PAYRECORD record[SIZE];` to be a local variable, size at least 13 Mbytes.

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh -- not even all conventional C programs will compile as C++ programs. `int *ptr = malloc(5);` will not compile as C++, but is idiomatic C. VLAs are conventional C, not supported by C++. `struct my_struct = { .x = 1, .y = 2 };` is legal, and common in C, but such designated initializers for `struct`s and arrays are not supported in Standard C++.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBowling for the example. I didn't know that struct syntax was legal in C.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `struct PAYRECORD` is wrong since there is no such type. You only have a `typedef` named `PAYRECORD`.

If you want to be able to use `struct PAYRECORD` as well as just `PAYRECORD`, change the definition of the `struct` to:

```
typedef struct PAYRECORD {
   char name[100];
   int age;
   float hrlyWage;
   float hrsWorked;
   float regPay;
   float otPay;
   float totalPay;
   DATE payDate;
} PAYRECORD;
```

If that's not your goal, change the use of `struct PAYRECORD` by just `PAYRECORD`.

Also, the line:

```
record[index].name = {'\0'};
```

in `newRecord` is not correct. You cannot assign to an array like that. Change it to:

```
record[index].name[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: I've made the changes here, and the program runs, only to crash immediately

Answer (score 1):

The `struct PAYRECORD` does not exist, the compiler has no idea how big that is.
Note that `PAYRECORD` is a typedef to an anonymous struct. So your function
should look like this:

```
int newRecord(PAYRECORD record[], int index){
    //set name to \0 so it can work as string
    record[index].name[0] = 0;
    index++;
    return index;
}
```

Also note that `{'\0'};` works only when initializing a array when you declare
it:

```
char arr1[10] = { '\0' }; // OK

char arr2[10];
arr2 = { '\0' }; // NOT OK
// error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
//  a = { '\0' };
//      ^
```

And when writing functions that take arrays as an argument, you should also pass
the size of the array.

```
int newRecord(PAYRECORD record[], int index, size_t len){
    if(record == NULL)
        return -1; // error, NULL passed

    if(index >= len)
        return -1; // error, cannot access array

    record[index].name[0] = 0;
    index++;
    return index;
}
```

And then you can call it from `main` like this:

```
PAYRECORD record[SIZE];
...

int index = 0;

if(newRecord(record, index, sizeof record / sizeof *record) != index)
{
    // error handling
}
```

This makes the code more robust. You always have to check the array boundaries,
otherwise you might read/write out of bounds. And also check that `NULL` has not
been passed as well, if you dereference `NULL`, your program will crash with
segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the parameter to newRecord could be a PAYARRAY, not an array directly; based on declaring

```
typedef struct { } PAYRECORD, PAYARRAY[SIZE];
int newRecord(PAYARRAY record, int index) {...}
int main(){
...
PAYARRAY record;
...
case 'A':
  index = newRecord(&record, index);
}
```

The compiler should be converting the PAYARRAY or PAYRECORD[] argument to a PAYRECORD * pointing to the first element, so use of the '&' is indicated for the function call.